# ¿Cómo mostrar una imagen Base64 en Swift?

Tags: imagen, xcode, base64, swift4

Recibo una imagen ya convertida a base 64 almacenada en mi base de datos 'Firebase', el siguiente paso es mostrar esa imagen en mi aplicación iOS escrita en Swift4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola si viene en base 64 yo utilizo algo a si para pasarla a imagen.

En mi ejemplo yo recibo la imagen en un Rest service, como resultado la variable imagen es un String inicialmente:

```
var imagen = JsonUtils.stringByJSON(r["imagen"])

if imagen != nil {
   obj.imagen = imagen
   let dataImg: Data = Data(base64Encoded: imagen, options: 
   NSData.Base64DecodingOptions())!

   obj.miImagen = UIImage(data: dataImg)
                }
```